# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.amp'

Tags: python, pytorch

I don't understand, apparently I managed to run "import torch" on jupyter notebook, but I get the error:

```
import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\graw\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 795, in <module>
    from torch.amp import autocast
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.amp'
```

I tried reinstalling torch: "pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url [https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118"](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118%22), but still the error. My old torch for cuda: torch-2.0.1+cu118
Maybe someone will help me, pls!!

--> I finally successfully fixed it. Copy and replace the torch from ...\python 3.10.6\Lib\site-packages\torch to the path C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch

Comment: Check if you import from the right module - shouldn't it be `torch.cuda.amp` ?

Comment: I can't import torch bro

Comment: I finally successfully fixed it. Copy and replace the torch from ...\python 3.10.6\Lib\site-packages\torch to the path C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\torch